# Numbered figure with caption in footnote

Tags: floats, captions, footnotes

The question about adding footnotes in floats or captions of these has been asked and debated often.

What is about floats in footnotes?

I can't seem to get a floating figure environment within a footnote. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[
DIV10,
a4paper,
pagesize,
english,
]{scrartcl} %scrreprt, scrartcl
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{``Floating'' figure in a footnote}

\blindtext\footnote{ %
\begin{figure}[htbp] %
\centering %
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo}\caption{\dots and a caption} %
\label{fig:demo} %
\end{figure}} %
\par
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Further is it typographically accepted to have a graphic in a footnote, if the only the text in the footnote refers to this figure? Nothing else in the whole document.

Comment: In your example code you're not using a `\caption`, so there's technically no need for the `figure` environment. That is, a single `\includegraphics` would suffice.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a floating environment (with no fixed place in the document) in a footnote that _has_ a fixed place.

Comment: I think you're echoing a common misconception about floats (`figures` and `tables`) as opposed to their contents (typically `\includegraphics` or `tabular`s).  The floating environments wrap something in a container that can be moved by TeX to fit the needs of the page layout. In the context of a footnote, you wouldn't want the graphic to move except with the footnote itself, so you shouldn't use a floating environment; you should just insert the graphic directly into the footnote.

Comment: @Werner: I do use caption, hence my idea with the minipage environment + `\captionof{}`.

Comment: I don't think that a footnote is a good place for a captioned figure. Maybe it's me, but I tend to dislike longish footnotes. If something is important it should go in the main body; otherwise it should go nowhere. `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating does not make a lot of sense in footnotes, hence I thought about it again and decided to use a minipage environment with the `\captionof` command instead. Please see the code below:

```
\documentclass[
DIV10,
a4paper,
pagesize,
english,
]{scrartcl} %scrreprt, scrartcl
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{``Floating'' figure in a footnote}

\blindtext\footnote{ %
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\centering %
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{demo} %
\captionof{figure}{\dots and a caption}
\label{fig:demo} %
\end{minipage}} %
\par
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems quite odd to me to have a figure in a footnote be included in the main list of figures. Elements in footnotes are typically numbered relative to the footnote itself not relative to the main document.

Comment: Alan: Can you give an example for the numbering relative to the footnote itself?

Comment: In my field, (linguistics) we number linguistic examples sequentially in the text (like math equations). However, if you use an example in a footnote, it gets numbered typically with lowercase roman, and the numbers restart each footnote.